# Использование открытых интерфейсов Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide

Возникла необходимость внести изменения в среду программирования Delphi. Это достаточно редкая необходимость, поэтому и информации по ней мало. Я нашёл только отрывочную документацию в справке и одну (!) [статью](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/delphi_open_interfaces.html) в интернете. Однако при попытке установить второй пример из этой статьи, я получаю ошибку доступа:

> Registration procedure, Unit1.Register
> in package
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Rad
> Studio\8.0\Bpl\Expert2try.bpl
> raised exception class
> EAccessViolation: Access violation at
> address 164B18F8 in module
> 'expert2try.bpl'. Read of address
> 00000000.

Вообще, из-за чего в процедуре Register может быть Access Violaiton? 
Что с этим делать?
Может быть, существуют какие нибудь более подробные статьи? Можно на английском.

Использую Delphi XE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На официальном сайте их есть:

- [Extending Delphi 2009 With OpenTools API: Getting Started](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39007)
- [Creating a Live Templates Scripting Engine](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37468)
- [Extending the Project Manager Context menu](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33978)

Кроме того:

- [Erik's Open Tools API FAQ](http://www.gexperts.org/opentools/)
- [Creating a OTA IDE Extension](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3870.asp?SK=)
- [Сustom syntax highlighting in Delphi 7](http://www.delphi-central.com/syntax_highlighting.aspx)

Вообще, копайте на тему *Delphi Open Tools API (OTA)*.